# How do I refresh Tablesorter's content-editable

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) working for a table, like so:

```
$("#mytable").tablesorter({
    // set initial sort
    sortList: tablesorting,
    emptyTo: 'none',
    widgets: ["stickyHeaders", "resizable", "filter", "editable"],
    widgetOptions: {
        ...
        editable_columns: [6],
        editable_editComplete: 'editComplete',
        editable_enterToAccept: true,
        editable_noEdit: 'missing'
    }
})
```

Periodically I replace some of the rows' HTML with jquery, however when this happens, the content-editable column no longer works.

How can I get tablesorter to reapply the content editable widget after changing the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editable widget was written to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). And only elements with a set `contenteditable` attribute are targeted (not set to `"false"`). So when you add a new row, make sure the table cells contain elements with `contenteditable="true"` attribute applied.

**Note** that IE does not allow making TR, TH or TD table cells directly editable, so add a div or span inside:

```
<tr>
    <td><div contenteditable="true">Foo</div></td>
    <td><div contenteditable="true">Bar</div></td>
</tr>
```

Once that is done, the editable widget should automagically allow work on that row.